# WordPress динамический URL

Tags: php, wordpress

есть страница /site.ru/page
нужно чтоб /site.ru/page/param1/param2/ обрабатывался как GET запрос и не показывало 404 страницу то есть "param1" и "param2" могут быть разными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этих целей в WordPress есть специальный функционал, основанный на [add_rewrite_rule()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule)